# Is there another way to access google APIs other than OAUTH2?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I'm trying to write a CLI script (ruby) to manage my youtube videos. Technically I'm updating a script that I used in 2012 to do this. It appears that since 2012, youtube has discontinued the simple client authentication mechanism and moved to OAUTH2 (though I'm not totally sure).

I'm wouldn't be the first to say that OAUTH2 is hell (just google it). It's been 3 hours and I still haven't gotten my old script to even authenticate with google (using the youtube_it ruby gem).

I simply do not understand why I would need to use OAUTH to access my own account on Google? What am I missing? I thought OAUTH was so that separate users could give access to applications to temporarily access their data.

Is there another way? What am I missing. As one blogger commented OAUTH2 is enough to make one want to change careers. Even the [lead dev quit the project](https://hueniverse.com/2012/07/26/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/).

Comment: All in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Youtube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) is specific in stating that if you're going to use Youtube API (or other Google APIs), you must learn how to use OAuth:

> If your application will use any API methods that require user
>   authorization, read the authentication guide to learn how to implement
>   OAuth 2.0 authorization.

Youtube has a [Ruby Quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby) which includes the OAuth process.

**I simply do not understand why I would need to use OAUTH to access my own account on Google?**

I think OAuth answers exactly that question, "how will Google products know if you are who you claim to be?"

Read the [OAuth Google guide for more info](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: my understanding of OAuth is a that it is was developed for apps to access 3rd party's objects, not the apps own objects. So gmail accepts who you are with a simple user/pw pair. That's basically how it used to be with the youtube api. If I'm accessing MY OWN data, that's all it seems I should need. What I don't understand is why I need to use an auth system designed for 3rd party access

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2 is an **authorization framework** that enables applications to obtain limited access to user accounts on an HTTP service, such as Facebook, GitHub, and google. It works by delegating user authentication to the service that hosts the user account, and authorizing third-party applications to access the user account. OAuth 2 provides authorization flows for web and desktop applications, and mobile devices.

for more detail study :-
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749